# Minimize image size for usage in web app

Tags: java, png

This might be too generic question, but I would appreciate any thoughts on the matter. Part of my web app is a servlet that generates an image. This servlet is used heavily since the resulting images might be, for example, displayed in several cells of a single client grid row. Hence my goal is to minimize the sizes of such images. Generated images are pretty straightforward - they are small bar/line charts (several bars/lines of different color). What would be the best format to create such images? PNG? JPEG? Also I have to create these images with java code, if that matters...

Comment: You can create with Java Jpeg and PNG images, see `BufferedImage`. As Thom suggested, try it out. PNGs can have an alpha. Jpeg does not support transparency. Think for the web I would go PNG.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's going to be a simple answer to this question. It's going to vary depending on color depth, image complexity, etc.

I would suggest an experimental approach. Generate a dozen JPEGs and a dozen PNGs and see what the image size is.

Answer (score 1):

png supports transparency and uses lossless compression.

jpeg does the opposite.

What about gif ? Could be suitable for bar charts and the like, it remains small and is lossless; but it only supports 256 colours.

In order of size it will (probably for a bar graph graphic), smallest to largest : gif jpeg png

Comment: If 256 are enough, I would pick GIF, as I do for most of my images that are displayed on websites I create.